# How the best way to make a function await response ECMA6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a small function to compare two arrays. After comparison, return an array with the values ​​for me to use as a callback.

However, I need to wait while the system obtains the data and generates the array, in the example, it is necessary to wait for the response of the functions before making the comparison.

I am starting ECMA6, and I found some possibilities to do this, such as AWAIT, YIELD, PROMISES, so what would be the best way to make this function wait for processing before processing the callback?

```
  function check (callback) {

   const friends = all_friends_id(callback)
   const family = all_family_id(callback)

   let difference = new Set(
     [...friends].filter(x => !family.has(x)))

   callback(diference)

  }
```

Comment: Where are you even doing anything async here?  Certainly `.filter()` isn't async.  Not even sure why you're using a callback at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to EC6/JS, you might find it easier to start with using callbacks. So your example would look something like this:

```
function check (callback) {
    all_friends_id( (friends) => {
        all_family_id( (family) => {
            let difference = new Set(
                 [...friends].filter(x => !family.has(x)))
            callback(difference)
        })
    })
}
```

After you've seen how to solve this task with callbacks, you might want to read up on promises. Promises solve the problem of "callback hell", in which a program has either a large number of nested callbacks, or complex callback relationships, or both.  But for this particular task you may find that a simple callback paradigm will work just fine.

Comment: this works fine =) I'm watching a YouTube video of how to use promise, to my understanding, it seems like it's doing the same thing ... only in a different way. I learned both ways \ o /

In your opinion, using promises is better in what situation?

Answer (score 1):

You asked for the "best" way.  This is the "best" because it is cleaner code.  And the `[...friends].filter(x => !family.has(x))` thing seems invalid so I corrected that.

```
const check = async () => {
   const friends = await all_friends_id(id);
   const family = await all_family_id(id);

   return friends.filter(f=> !family.includes(f))
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have some preamble commentary explaining why this is an answer

Comment: @Soren, I will add it, but "why this is an answer" is questioning whether it is an answer or not, which it obviously is, so thats just an insult, and given the question the preamble is just going to be hot-air.  Its self-explanatory.

Comment: your answer was flagged for deletion by the system "due to low quality" -- so im not insulting you but trying to advice you on how to make your answer better.

Comment: The OP asked about ES6, but async and await are ES7.